# Micronaut: test is failing with Page not foun, but the page can be accessed normally via browser

Tags: java, gradle, junit, micronaut

I was learning how to use Micronaut to create REST services but something I can't see is wrong with my tests settings and whatever I change in my code or in gradle I always get an annoying 'Page not found' error when running the tests but not when the application is running normally.

I have a class named `App` in the package `br.com.myproject`. In this class I have only the main method, as follows:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    Micronaut.run(App.class);
}
```

In a subpackage `br.com.myproject.controllers` I have a class `HelloController` annotated with `@Get("/hello")` that should respond with a single "Hello, World!" text and it does normally when I access it through the browser:

```
package br.com.myproject.controllers;

@Controller("/hello")
public class HelloController {

    @Get("/")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String index() {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }

}
```

In the tests directory, I have the class `HelloControllerTest` that should assure my `/hello` endpoint works properly. But unfortunately, my test is failing with a `PageNotFound` exception.

My class test is as follows:

```
package br.com.myproject.controllers;

public class HelloControllerTest {

    private static EmbeddedServer server;
    private static HttpClient client;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setupServer() {
        server = ApplicationContext.run(EmbeddedServer.class);
        client = server
                .getApplicationContext()
                .createBean(HttpClient.class, server.getURL());
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void stopServer() {
        if (client != null)
            client.stop();

        if (server != null)
            server.stop();
    }

    @Test
    public void testHello() throws Exception {
        HttpRequest<String> httpRequest = HttpRequest.GET("/hello");
        String body = client.toBlocking().retrieve(httpRequest);
        Assert.assertNotNull(body);
        Assert.assertEquals(body, "Hello, World!");
    }

}
```

And, for last, my gradle settings:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:4.0.3'
        classpath 'io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.6.RELEASE'
        classpath 'net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.15'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.6.RELEASE'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '4.0.3'
    id 'application'
    id 'java'
    id 'net.ltgt.apt-idea' version '0.15'
}

group 'br.com.myproject'
version '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor 'io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java:1.0.0'

    compile 'io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client:1.0.0'
    compile 'io.micronaut:micronaut-http-server-netty:1.0.0'
    compile 'io.micronaut:micronaut-inject:1.0.0'
    compile 'io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime:1.0.0'
    compileOnly 'io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java:1.0.0'

    runtime 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java:1.0.0'
}

shadowJar {
    mergeServiceFiles()
}

mainClassName = 'br.com.myproject.App'
```

Both my tests and my gradle settings were written based on a code example in Micronaut documentation ([this one](https://github.com/micronaut-guides/creating-your-first-micronaut-app)). And somehow the tests in the code example works properly.

For instance, these are what I tried before asking here:

- Changed the versions of dependencies to match versions in code example: it didn't work;
- Put all classes under same package (`br.com.myproject`): it didn't work;
- Copy/paste the gradle settings of the example code into my gradle settings and changing the package names properly: it didn't work;
- Print out the URL used in the test just to check if it is correct: it is correct, but still 'Page not found' is thrown.

Everything works fine, however, when I run the application and type the address into the browser.

I have googled the keywords "micronaut test page not found" and similars but I found no useful articles that helped me to fix this error.

Just to mention: I am not completely familiar with gradle configuration and thus I suspect I might be lacking something here.

Does anyone have any idea what I may be missing?

I appreciate any tip.

Thanks =)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Micronaut, but when you do a "real" launch you are running `App.class`, and I don't see a reference to that anywhere in your test.

Comment: @chrylis The test does not need to make any mention of `App.class`.  The code he shows there is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/jonathansouzanotfound.  I have pasted your code directly into that project (and added missing import statements) and the test passes.

```
 $ ./gradlew clean test

> Task :compileJava

... 

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4s
5 actionable tasks: 5 executed
```

Comment: You didn't indicate how you are running the test but if you are running the test from an IDE without engaging Gradle, make sure that you have annotation processors enabled in the IDE.  See https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#ideSetup.

Comment: I hadn't tried to run the tests directly through the terminal. I did it now and it worked properly. It seems something is wrong with my IntelliJ settings. I already assured that 'Enable annotation processor' is enabled but still it fails. I'll compare with the settings in the project of the example, that works well. Thank you a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Get("/")
    @Produces (MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String index(){
        return "Hello World";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Referred from [Jeff's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3533584/jeff-scott-brown) comment and answered it here to make it more visible

Make sure annotation processing is enabled in the IDE if you running the tests through IDE.

[image]